# Increasing all levels in a list by 1 in a word document

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a word document which has been divided into different parts using a multilevel list. The thing is that I need to copy the whole doc into another higher level document. So is there a way to automatically increase the whole multilevel list one level further?

EDIT 01:
The current style is like this:

```
1- OldLevel1
  1-1- OldLevel2
    1-1-1- OldLevel3
2- OldLevel1
  2-1- OldLevel2
```

I want to change it to be like this:

```
1- NewLevel1
  1-1- OldLevel1
      1-1-1- OldLevel2
        1-1-1-1- OldLevel3
    1-2- OldLevel1
      1-2-1- OldLevel2
```

Comment: "increase one level further"? Each element is 1 level more-nested? Select all and press tab. Perhaps you're after "start numbering at" "2" / "B"?

Comment: @RJFalconer the document is like more than 400 pages, one can't easily press tab to increase list levels! take a look at the edit part.

Comment: Why can't one use tab to accomplish that? You can highlight 400 pages if necessary (`Ctrl-A`), or move through and highlight sections that you want to alter. I don't understand why this would be a problem, please elaborate.

Comment: @Steve while selecting the whole document, pressing tab will not increase the level of a heading in multi-level list. It just increases the indent.

Comment: This *should* be an *obvy* *major* time-saving feature (and one I can't imagine is sig hard *after* already supporting: a) multi-level lists, b) changing list level of any one item (via Tab / Shift-Tab) and c) changing indention of a multiitem *subset* of multilevel list (the latter,  btw, imho, is pretty useless inside a multi-level list cuz: a) one usually wants a consistent indentation scheme for the *entire* multilevel list and b) there's already a feature for changing the indentations of the *entire* multilevel list).    It's unbelievable MS hasn't added it after DECADES!?

Comment: Btw, it's not just needed to insert multilevel list into another multilevel list in another doc. 
 It's also needed when one often decides that an entire subset of a multilevel list should be under another item, e.g., a single parent item turns into multiple parent items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description you have your multi level list linked to heading styles, if yes then the easiest way is probably to use a macro, like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim p As Paragraph
    For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If Left(p.Style, 7) = "Heading" Then p.Style = Left(p.Style, 8) & CInt(Right(p.Style, 1)) + 1
    Next p
End Sub
```

Note: modify the code if your style are not named like "Heading x".

Comment: Excellent! exactly what I have been looking for. saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Simply highlight the lines you want to move out or in (no need to select everything, just the lines you want to move), and press either <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Shift-Tab</kbd>. Each press of tab will indent/outdent the entire selection, as well as change the levels of those lines in the list.

Comment: Not working for me.  It increases indent only (not also list level).  Tab/Shift+Tab only increases/decreases list level for me if only 1 or 0 item is selected.

-Microsoft® Word for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2208 Build 16.0.15601.20148) 64-bit  and any prior version 365 or not I can recall..